# Javascript variables math

Tags: javascript, variables, math

I am making a game with javascript where you can buy fish and I am trying to figure out how to make it so that when `function agf()` is executed the number in `<p id="money">10</p>` is subtracted by 2. So far I have tried:

```
var m=document.getElementById('money').value;
function agf() {
  if(m>1) {
    var pay=(m-2);
    document.getElementById('money').innerhtml=pay;
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with addition now but it is not working. I tried switching var pay=(m-2); to var sell=(m+2); and then document.getElementById('money').innerHTML=pay; has sell at the end instead of pay.

Answer (score 2):

- Fetching the current value should be done inside the function so that you're always getting the current value.
- The `.value` should be `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`.
- To be safe, you should convert the value to a number.
- The second `.innerhtml` should be `innerHTML` *(notice the capitalization)*.
- You're missing closing brackets

---

```
function agf() {
    var m=Number(document.getElementById('money').innerHTML);
    if(m>1) {
        var pay=(m-2);
        document.getElementById('money').innerHTML=pay;
    }
}
```